# Why doesn't google-chrome get the multi-window indicator on the Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, dock

I am a huge sucker for aesthetic quirks, and it's not so much that this bothers me but I really can't help but notice that chrome doesn't seem to get the same treatment on the dock as other programs.

To demonstrate exactly what I'm talking about I opened a couple windows in Chrome and a couple in Mozilla and you'll notice the difference from this picture, look left center of the sprites...

[image]

`Sorry if it's small but if you can't see it you will never care anyway...`

Why does this happen? (or I guess why doesn't it happen?)

Comment: Just a straight up guess here but perhaps Google just did not optimize Chrome for Unity, they don't put it in the repos. I have a similar issue with Amarok, it does not integrate well, make a new icon for every window (on Gnome too). You could install Chromium and see if it is the same, if that integrates well, it looks like Google did not optimize. Apart from that I don't really see a good explanation been given for this.

Comment: I know they spent some time testing on linux because Netflix works out of the box, and that's no coincidence.  I see 3 possibilities they either didn't notice or don't care, the idea that Google couldn't fix it seems unlikely...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they fixed it. If anyone wants to post some details about what you think they did (or if you want to go find the change log) that'd be cool.